# Creating simple popup on click in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, popup

I have different figures created in my Django project.(icon with text, point,circle etc)
but I try to create a simple popup with the coordinates when I click the mouse but I have a error:

My code is from an example, seen here

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([-0.92, 52.96], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 6
    })
});

var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
map.addOverlay(popup);

map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var prettyCoord = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'), 2);
    popup.show(evt.coordinate, '<div><h2>Coordinates</h2><p>' + prettyCoord + '</p></div>');
});
```

I get this error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: ol.Overlay.Popup is not a constructor.`

when trying to create --> `var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();`

Comment: OpenLayers library has no native `ol.Overlay.Popup()` object. If you need popup, you have to construct it yourself from `ol.Overlay` (see example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html) or use some plugin, like for example https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-popup

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned what are the javaScript and css files you have used in your page.

By looking at the error `ol.Overlay.Popup` is not a constructor, I understand that you have included only the openlayers basic javaScript and css.

For using the Popup functionality, you need to include the `ol-ext.js` and `ol-ext.css` in you page.

You can download the Openlayers extension from [here](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext).

I have tested your code after including the above files. It worked fine.